# AMP Email images automatically loading?

Tags: amp-email

If you setup AMP email / Get approved.

Will your subscribers still need to "approve pictures from sender" or will images be automatically loaded?

Just trying to understand, if it's worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Gmail, the "Dynamic email" feature will only be enabled if the image setting is set to "Always allow external images". If the setting is set to "Always ask" (which would be the case in your question), then AMP emails will fall back to static HTML/plain text emails.

You can see a short blurb about this fact in the description of the image setting in Gmail. Also see the `HIDING_IMAGES` fallback reason at https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/debugging-dynamic-email.

Comment: Sadly, this means about 40% - 50% of recipients won't be able to see your AMP content.

Comment: Do you have data backing up that percentage range? I wouldn't expect it to be that high. The image setting is set to allow external images by default for consumer accounts. Normally only privacy-aware users would disable external images to prevent tracking. It doesn't make sense to enable AMP for Email for such users, as AMP for Email allows tracking. If they don't want tracking, then they don't want AMP for Email.

Comment: I've checked my source for that and it is very very old (2014) and since then Gmail has made loading images the default setting, so these days much more people will be showing images. Sorry.